# load a jar file dynamically via jnlp

Tags: java, jnlp, urlclassloader

I have a running and tested code, where I can load a jar file and all the dependencies to the class path.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;


public URLClassLoader loadjarFile(String path) throws IOException {

        URLClassLoader sysLoader;
        URL u = null;

        try {

            File file = new File("D:\\test\\mytest.jar");
            u = file.toURI().toURL();
            sysLoader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

            Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
            Class[] parameters = new Class[] { URL.class };
            Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);

            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(sysLoader, new Object[] { u });

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
            throw new IOException("Error, could not add file " + u.toExternalForm() + " to system classloader");
        }

        return sysLoader;
}
```

What I need now is not to have the .jar file in a local path but directly like we perform when we go to the browser via a button that calls a .jnlp.

Basically to call e.g. **xpto/test.jnlp**. Replace File file = new File("D:\test\mytest.jar") to something like URLfile = new URL("xpto/test.jnlp").

It is possible? How can I adapt the code above to perform via jnlp and use the rest?

Many thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: why do you want to use jnlp?  why not just download the jar to a local file and load it?

Comment: Because using JNLP download time will be saved. This is for automation n2n test and to open directly the jar file from where the Network element is and to similar, to the human interface